# Calculate $\int\sqrt{(x^2+1)}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

Calculate $I$ =$\int\sqrt{(x^2+1)}dx$
I have tried calculating it using integration by parts:
$$f'(x) = 1, f(x) = x$$
$$g(x) = \sqrt{x^2+1}, g'(x) = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$ 
$$\int\sqrt{x^2+1}dx = x\sqrt{x^2+1} - \int\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$
Then I make the substitution:
$$x^2+1 = u$$ 
$$2xdx = du$$
$$ I = \frac{1}{2}\int{\frac{1}{\sqrt{u}}}du = \sqrt u$$
Substituting back $x$ I get:
$$\int\sqrt{(x^2+1)}dx = x\sqrt{x^2+1} - (x^2+1)^{\frac{1}{4}}  $$
What am I doing wrong? Because I plugged this into an integral calculator and the answer is $\ln(|\sqrt{x^2+1}+x|) +x\sqrt{x^2+1}$.

Comment: Hint: $$x=\sinh u\implies dx=\cosh u\,du\;\implies \int\sqrt{x^2+1}dx=\int\cosh^2u\,du...$$

Comment: I have no clue what $sinh$ means, this is an exercise in an introductory chapter to indefinite integrals and integration by parts, it is supposed to be some basic stuff. Thanks for your help anyway, I appreciate it.

Comment: Then you better learn it and study fast, as you're going to need it for this exercise. The *hyperbolic functions* $\;\sinh\,,\,\,\cosh\;$ and etc., are defined to be: $$\sinh x:=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}2\;,\;\;;\cosh x:=\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}2\;,\;\;etc.$$

Comment: I meant that it sure can be solved without these advanced techniques since we were barely introduced to integrals.

Comment: Yes, it can surely be solved otherwise, but hyperbolic functions are not :advanced: stuff. They are just some kind of exponential functions and sums! They really are not hard

Comment: Why are the hyperbolic functions more advanced than the trigonometric ones?

Comment: You can use the Euler's substitution and you can see this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your IBP should have given $$\int\sqrt{x^2+1}dx=x\sqrt{x^2+1}-\int\frac{x^2dx}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}=x\sqrt{x^2+1}-\int\sqrt{x^2+1}dx+\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}.$$Rearranging,$$\int\sqrt{x^2+1}dx=\frac{x\sqrt{x^2+1}+\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}}{2}.$$For the last integral, use $x=\tan t$.

Comment: Oh yeah.. what a silly mistake, thanks a lot.

Comment: @RaduGabriel I hope you realize that if you sub $x=tant$ in your integral to begin with, things will become MUCH easier from the get-go!

Comment: @imranfat [They will and they won't](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_secant_cubed).

Comment: @J.G. True, but I thought of the integral of $sec^3x$ to be kind of a staple integral, I mean in Stewart Calculus, they work it out for you as an example. You just copy the result.

Comment: @imranfat Either one could be the staple, depending on the textbook. One could argue Stewart made the better choice as to which would *deserve* it.